# Calculated Score in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I still create Application Quiz in SharePoint Designer
I have a problem with it.
1. user will choose QuizList, the user will choose QuizTitle (e.g : QuizTitle --> Fruit with 6 questions)

1. Every QuizTitle have different amount questions ( it can be 6/7/8 questions)
2. user will answer the question, to the next question user must click button next
3. when the button next clicked by user, automatically the answer from the question will be saved in coloumn MarkAnswer
4. User must answer the question until finish.
5. At the last question, I have button finish. In my logic, the last answer not yet saved in coloumn Mark Answer. So, when user click button finish I want make 3 action in one time. When user click button finish it will be :

a) First : the last answer will be saved in coloumn Mark Answer.

b) Second: calculate the score from first question until last questions.

c) Third : direct to other page

Could you help me, please? Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is older than three months, the poster of the question hasn't been seen for three months and it contains no answers or no upvoted answers. If you want it re-opened, cast a reopen vote, or flag for moderate attention. [Reference](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/1014/6382).